# how to store checkbox item in a database through php

Tags: php, mysql

i am coading huge html form which store data in database through php but my checkbox code is not working

////check box code////

```
<li>Mother </li><table><tr><td><input type="checkbox" name="mdeceased"               value="deceased">deceased</td>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="malive" value="alive">alive</td></tr>
<tr><td><input type="checkbox" name="mretired" value="retired">retired</td>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="minservice" value="inservice">in service</td>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="mbusiness" value="business">business</td></tr>
```

///php code for checkbox for making variable and then using in the query ///

```
$mysql = new mysqli('localhost','root','ramsha','scholarships_system') or die ('you\'re     dead');
if(!empty($_POST['submit'])) {
$mdeceased =$_POST['mdeceased'];
$malive = $_POST['malive'];
$mretired = $_POST['mretired'];
$minservice = $_POST['minservice'];
$mbusiness = $_POST['mbusiness'];


$query = "INSERT INTO student _details      VALUES('$mdeceased','$malive','$mretired','$minservice','$mbusiness')";

if($updateDb = $mysql->query($query) or die($mysql->error)) {
        echo "Congrats!";
    }
```

///error is coming ///
Notice: Undefined index: mdeceased in C:\wamp\www\student form filling\htmlform.php on line 91

only $alive is accepting 
what to do

Comment: check for empty values before inserting, you can use `isset()`, also, you must use prepared statement (parametrized) to prevent from SQL injection attacks.

Comment: Just a small comment: Your HTML is invalid. In an `ul` you can't have a `table` outside a `li`.

Comment: checkboxes which are NOT checked in the form are NOT submitted. If the checkbox's name doesn't show up in $_POST, you know it wasn't checked.

Comment: On another note, why not have the Mother living information as Radio buttons instead of checkboxes? If they are both checkboxes, then someone can select that Mother is living AND deceased.

Comment: hey ckpeppar02 i follow your advice and change my code into radio buttons it works also but what ever i chose  from radio buttons it gives only 0 into my data base what to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended the open `<input>` tags and just did a null check. It started working.

Problem was you were trying to save a variable that was never set/initialized.

```
<?php
$mysql = new mysqli('localhost','root','Subha#143','test') or die ('you\'re     dead');
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
$mdeceased =isset($_POST['mdeceased'])?$_POST['mdeceased']:null;
$malive = isset($_POST['malive'])?$_POST['malive']:null;
$mretired = isset($_POST['mretired'])?$_POST['mretired']:null;
$minservice = isset($_POST['minservice'])?$_POST['minservice']:null;
$mbusiness = isset($_POST['mbusiness'])?$_POST['mbusiness']:null;

$query = "INSERT INTO student_details VALUES('$mdeceased','$malive','$mretired','$minservice','$mbusiness')";

if($updateDb = $mysql->query($query) or die($mysql->error)) {
        echo "Congrats!";
    }
}else{echo("post is not set");}
?>
```

Comment: thanku Srihari but now i just change my code from check box to radio button and it works also but one problem what ever i chose in my radio buttons only 0 goes in my data base what to do

Comment: In case of radio buttons, have the same name for the same set of data. http://www.phpforkids.com/php/php-forms-get-post-checkbox-radio-data.php provides a usable tutorial. And remember, if you are doing an echo of values, use `.` and not `+` to view the values.

Comment: Here , isset ?: use for if else statement ?

Comment: @AmranurRahman yes. The ternary operator is being used for null check and the same thing can be achieved using an if else block.